# Receiving input from the user without pressing enter Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, shell, input

I would like to receive an input from the user without having to press enter in python 3. I've seen people use "getch" but I need to be able to run this in the shell, and getch doesn't seem to work too smoothly with that. All I need is something like this:

```
myVariable = raw_input() #raw input isn't in python 3, hence the problem
```

Comment: The equivalent of ``raw_input`` in Python3 is just ``input``, but it will have exactly the same behaviour – enter is required.

Comment: I would like my code to not require enter to be pressed - thanks anyway